# Sitecore User Group April 2019 Meetup - Queen City, Manchester, NH

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

We are wicked stoked to announce the April'19 meetup of the Queen City Sitecore User Group!

Two excellent presentation are lined up for this SUG:

Sitecore Solr Search with eDisMax - Steven Striga, Technical Lead at Verndale

ROAD TRIP: Discover the Wild World of Sitecore on Azure PaaS - Grant Killian, Sitecore MVP and Solutions Architect at Rackspace

Date & Time (EST):- Wednesday, April, 10, 2019 6:00 PM

Date & Time (UTC):- Wednesday, April, 10, 2019 10:00 PM

Venue:- SilverTech Inc, 196 Bridge Street, Manchester, NH 03104

[Click here](https://www.meetup.com/Queen-City-Sitecore-User-Group/events/260081916/) for more details and RSVP.

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins in 2 days